# How to generate test data for models created by loopback over mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, loopbackjs, loopback, test-data

I have 45 models created in loopback with relations. I don't know how to insert test data into these collations by keeping relations.

**Update:**

models are not independent they have defined relations **has one** or **has many** or **belongs to** relations. therefore test data should be paying attention to the relations.

Comment: You will need to enter a lot more details plus a clear question in order to get good answers here.

Comment: @dnickless, Thanks, I need a way to generate huge test data with considering relations between models.

Comment: I hope to find some good ways, I have the same problem some times.